# Removing the scrollbar from JSFiddle tablesorter

Tags: tablesorter, jsfiddle

I've created a tablesorter through JSFiddle, and the best way apparently to show it on a site is through adding /show at the end. However when I add this to my site, and all the other ways I've tried there is a scrollbar within the tablesorter and the heading can be scrolled up because of the results and edit in JSFiddle.

I know that probably sounds like rubbish, so I've attached a link to my site where it apepears, as you can see it is scrollable.

Is there a way of disabling the scrollbar in the HTML, CSS or JavaScript so that when it appears on my site it is fixed.

I hope ive been clear, thanks.

Link - eylestom.wix.com/tenation#!releases/c16vn

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you mean the scrollbar in the iframe that contains your JSFiddle?  I think that iframe is taller than the "tabs" div containing it.  I made an inline change to the height of the iframe to 530px (allowing for your header block) and the scrollbar isn't displayed.

So, I think you could just make the iframe smaller, or make your containing div taller, or set its overflow to 'hidden'.  But, your page looks like it's going to contain a lot of data down the road.  I'd suggest you look at adding the 'stickyheader' or 'scroller' widgets to your tablesorter to manage the overflow more gracefully.

```
<iframe src="//fiddle.jshell.net/tome98/abkNM/5961/show/light/" sandbox="allow-forms allow-popups allow-scripts allow-same-origin" style="height: 530px;"></iframe>
```